# ¿Cómo desplegar en distintas filas los meses correspondientes a un rango de fechas en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada **faltas** con algunos datos de ejemplo:

| id | empleado | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1001 | 2021-06-01 |
| 0002 | 1001 | 2021-06-02 |
| 0003 | 1001 | 2021-07-20 |
| 0004 | 1001 | 2021-07-21 |
| 0005 | 1002 | 2021-07-01 |
| 0006 | 1003 | 2021-07-01 |

Lo que busco desplegar son los días (con orden ascendente) entre las fechas 01/06/2021 y 31/07/2021, en los que tuvo faltas el empleado **1001** separados por su respectivo mes. Dejo a continuación un ejemplo de lo que se busca obtener:

| faltas | mes |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2 | 6 |
| 20,21 | 7 |

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha) ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha) ASC) AS faltas,
    MONTH(fecha) AS mes FROM faltas WHERE empleado = 1001 AND fecha BETWEEN '2021/06/01' AND '2021/07/31'
```

Con la consulta expuesta anteriormente me acerco al resultado esperado, pero finalmente lo que obtengo es lo siguiente:

| faltas | mes |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2,20,21 | 7 |

¿Cómo podría modificar mi consulta para obtener el resultado deseado?
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Sólo agrega `GROUP BY year(fecha), month(fecha)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casi lo tienes, únicamente te falta el `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha)
      ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha) ASC
  ) AS faltas,
  MONTH(fecha) AS mes
  FROM faltas
  WHERE empleado = 1001 
  AND fecha BETWEEN '2021/06/01' AND '2021/07/31'
  GROUP BY MONTH(fecha);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, se me escapó algo tan sencillo. Precisamente esa es la solución